# AWS DMS RDS MySQL 8 Can't initialize character set unknown

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aws-dms

I am trying to run a replication task (CDC) between a AWS RDS MYSQL 8.0.11 database and a Redshift cluster using DMS.

I run into the error :

```
Error 2019 (Can't initialize character set unknown (path: compiled_in)) connecting to MySQL server
```

Replication Instance engine version :   3.1.3

Char sets used by the RDS MySQL instance :

```
-- SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%';
‘character_set_client’,‘utf8mb4’
‘character_set_connection’,‘utf8mb4’
‘character_set_database’,‘utf8mb4’
‘character_set_filesystem’,‘binary’
‘character_set_results’,‘utf8mb4’
‘character_set_server’,‘utf8mb4’
‘character_set_system’,‘utf8’
‘character_sets_dir’,‘/rdsdbbin/mysql-8.0.11.R2/share/charsets/’
```

Comment: I also tried with a fresh RDS MySQL 8.0.15 and DMS engine 3.1.4, same result

Comment: I just had a answer from AWS : they recommend using DMS 3.3 (Launched last week)

Comment: DMS 3.3 didn't work any better

Answer (score 0):

I donot think DMS supports MYSQL 8.X as yet. Supported versions are explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MySQL.html).

Comment: According to this thread https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=307488 AWS engineers' position on the subject seems unclear.

Answer (score 0):

According to the AWS documentation:

> AWS Database Migration Service (AWS DMS) 3.1.1 Release Notes AWS DMS
>   now supports all 4-byte character sets, such as UTF8MB4, and so on.
>   This feature works without any configuration changes.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_ReleaseNotes.html

Some people has gotten this to work using this method:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=910772

Comment: I am the author of that awsforum post you linked. When I wrote this post and this stackoverflow Question the version of DMS was 3.1.4 (stable) and 3.3 (beta). This are still the latest versions.